# Export from DataGridView

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I need to create a button on a PowerShell GUI to save the content of a DataGridView when pressed.  This needs to open a file dialogue box to select the destination and give it a file name.

See code for what I have already tried

```
$btnSave_Click={
    $saveFile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $saveFile.Filter = "Comma Delimited (*.csv) | *.csv "
    $saveFile.FileName
    if ($saveFile.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK')
    {
        $results.SelectAll()
        $results.ClipboardCopyMode = 'EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText'
        $results.GetClipboardContent().GetData('Text') | Out-File 
    $saveFile.FileName
    }
}
```

Error received is

```
ERROR: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
ERROR: char:4
ERROR: +             $results.SelectAll()
ERROR: +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [],     
RuntimeException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
ERROR:
ERROR: The property 'ClipboardCopyMode' cannot be found on this object.  
Verify that the property exists and can be set.
ERROR: char:4
ERROR: +             $results.ClipboardCopyMode   
= 'EnableAlwaysIncludeHea ...
ERROR: +                
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [],   
RuntimeException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
ERROR:
ERROR: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
ERROR: char:4
ERROR: +             $results.GetClipboardContent().GetData('Text') | 
Out ...
ERROR: +             
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], 
RuntimeException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
ERROR:
```

Comment: you don't save the `$results` so the variable doesn't exist...

Comment: first of all you need to verify the '$results' variable, Error shows that its NULL.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you meant

```
$result = $DataGridViewdata.selectall()
```